# Customize a mysql_error duplicate error message?

Tags: java, mysql

im getting "Duplicate entry 'username' for key PRIMARY" error message, but I would love for it to read "This username already exists".

Is that possible?
If so, where and how would I go about changing that?

Comment: Catch the exception and throw a different one.

Comment: Where are you getting it? Where do you want to show a different message?

Comment: @Andreas I agree with you, but this is actually a good question (though apparently already asked).  Simply catch an appropriate exception then check the JDBC error code and if it matches to the duplicate key error, then display a custom message.